# PHP DOCX convert to HTML

Tags: php, docx

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I convert a docx document to html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php)

I need a simple way to take uploaded docx files using PHP and turn them into HTML with basically the same formatting such as bold, italics, fonts-sizes, etc...