# Is it possible to dynamically generate a HTML page on a server with Microsoft Word .docx files?

Tags: php, ms-word

Let me put my question simply: is it possible for a (PHP) server to dynamically generate a HTML page using a Microsoft Word .docx document that is also on the server? I want the content of the Microsoft Word document to load up as HTML within the body tag.

For example, if the Microsoft Word document consisted of only the phrase "Hello world" and nothing else, I want the output HTML to be like this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Random</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Hello world</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are putting yourself the wrong question.
You will have to use php to read your document and based on that, to output it in html.
Take a look here: [How can I convert a docx document to html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible. The tricky part is reading the contents of the document. Once you have that, it is trivial to display the contents within your HTML.

For reading the contents, I recommend you do a Google search or search here on SO - there are several libraries that can help you:

- [Docvert](http://static.holloway.co.nz/docvert/index.html)
- [PHPLiveDicX](http://www.phplivedocx.org/downloads/)