# How to parse docx and doc file into html text in php?

Tags: php, docx, doc

code:

```
<?php
    $filePath = "upload_resume/".$upload_resume;
    function readDocx($filePath) 
    {
        $zip = new ZipArchive;
        $dataFile = 'word/document.xml';
        if (true === $zip->open($filePath)) 
        {
            if (($index = $zip->locateName($dataFile)) !== false) 
            {
                $data = $zip->getFromIndex($index);
                $zip->close();
                $xml = DOMDocument::loadXML($data, LIBXML_NOENT | LIBXML_XINCLUDE | LIBXML_NOERROR | LIBXML_NOWARNING);
                $contents = explode('\n',strip_tags($xml->saveXML()));
                $text = '';
                foreach($contents as $i=>$content) 
                {
                    $text .= $contents[$i];
                }
                return $text;
            }
            $zip->close();
        }
        return "";
    }
?>
```

In this code I have a folder where we upload docx or doc file but now I want to read or parse docx and doc file into html text but now its not working yet. It show me nothing where $upload_resume is fetching from database. So, How can I read this file in php ?Please help me.

Thank You

Comment: There is a library called [PHPOffice/Word](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I convert a docx document to html using php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4587216/how-can-i-convert-a-docx-document-to-html-using-php)